# Magit unignore file

Tags: magit

When in magit, I pressed `i` on a file and asked if I would like to ignore the file locally or globally. I chose locally.

I assumed that it would write a line in my `.gitignore` file but unfortunately that's not the case and I can't find any reference for un-ignoring said file.

How can I un-ignore a file ignored locally with magit?

Version info:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-07-05
Magit 20190202.1535, Git 2.20.1, Emacs 26.1, gnu/linux
```

Comment: Probably look in `.git/info/exclude`

Comment: @phils - wow there it is, thanks! Could you submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.git/info/exclude` is where "local" (only in your working copy; not tracked) ignore patterns are listed.  This is a standard feature of Git.

Magit writes to either that file or `.gitignore`, as required.

Comment: So if I'm correct: "locally" writes to `.git/info/exclude`, whereas "globally" writes to `.gitignore`?

Comment: Yes, the "globally" terminology seems to have been introduced in v2.90.0, and it does indeed mean the repository's tracked `.gitignore` file.  The term might be considered a bit ambiguous, as Git provides a third ignore option which is arguably "more global" (setting `core.excludesFile` in `~/.gitconfig`, which affects *any* repository), which I think easily leads to the misunderstanding you experienced -- particularly when `.git/info/exclude` is unfamiliar.  Perhaps the phrasing in the pop-up needs to be reconsidered.

Comment: Jonas has improved the terminology and command set on the transient branch, which should land in master soon.  The gitignore popup includes "shared at toplevel (.gitignore)" => `magit-gitignore-in-topdir`, "shared in subdirectory (path/to/.gitignore)" => `magit-gitignore-in-subdir`, "privately (.git/info/exclude)" => `magit-gitignore-in-gitdir`, and "privately for all repositories (<core.excludesfile>)" => `magit-gitignore-on-system`.

Comment: https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/26e45568e3cd90f6a062de22ae9673462d286af1 and https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/ab78039a03faa47076c66f90c02b5b242c949d87 show that the docstrings are likewise clarified, so everything seems to have been taken care of already :)

Comment: The transient branch has now been merged to master, so early-adopters will be seeing these changes now, and presumably everyone else will see it from version 2.91.